# Photon, PlayFab, & Unity3d - Game won't run in Iran unless VPN is used. Works fine in other countries

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I've a template (Unity) similar to 8 Ball Pool (Multiplayer).
This template uses Playfab and Photon Network. 
I configured PlayFab and Photon, made a build and could play successfully online. 
The problem is that when someone from "Iran" tries to play it, it does not continue and remain to the initialization where (perhaps) PlayFab is being initialized. 
The game could run perfectly when VPN is used.

What should be done in order to make it play in Iran too? 
Thanks

Comment: There may be nothing you can do. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship_in_Iran

Comment: Alright. There are some games which are Multiplayer and can be run in Iran. So perhaps they are using some other or a custom server not under banned list of Internet in Iran.

Comment: Anyways... Perhaps I would need to host Photon on custom server in order to make it work. Because the target audience for the game is merely Iran. I think Google Play is banned from Iran and there is an alternate marketplace called CafeBazaar.

Comment: Its really weird by the way. Iran should not ban Photon or gaming servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. Its because Photon is American company and due to sanctions you cannot run it in Iran.
If you still want to use Photon services in Iran, you can buy license for Photon and then host it on some server which runs in Iran.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behavior and not caused by Iran banning Photon, like a comment suggested, but by Photon Cloud using Softlayer hosting centers for its server and Softlayer blocking traffic from Iran to their servers because they are an US company and hence need to comply to US law, which means that they are required to block traffic from Iran due to the US embargo of Iran.

Countries that are currently blocked by Softlayer due to US embargoes and hence can't use Photon Cloud are:
    Cuba
    Iran
    North Korea
    Sudan
    Syria

Playfab is an US company, so they are not allowed by their government, to offer their services to Iranian users, just like Softlayer.

If you host Photon servers inside of Iran yourself, then Iranian users could connect to them.
However due to the US embargo on Iran Exit Games (the company behind Photon) is not permitted to make business with customers from Iran, so you can't buy the necessary licenses for Photon server if you are from Iran yourself.
As your profile suggest that you are from Pakistan this should not affect you, so you could buy the required Photon licenses and then host Photon yourself on servers that are provided by some Iranian hosting company.

Be aware that you will run into similar issues with pretty much every commercial software, as the companies behind most software are either located in the US or at least have a lot more customers and other business relations in the US than they could potentially ever get in Iran and hence need to adhere to the embargo, because by not doing so they would risk their US-business.